# Get records from last hour or last 20 items if there is none in the last hour

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I have a chat system and I want to show messages sent in the last hour, but I also want to show the last 20 messages no matter how long ago they were sent.

Is there a way I can do this in.a SQL query?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chat` (
  `id`        INT(11) UNSIGNED                                                                            NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id`   INT(11) UNSIGNED                                                                            NOT NULL,
  `item_id`   INT(11) UNSIGNED                                                                            NOT NULL,
  `message`   TEXT                                                                                        NOT NULL,
  `recipient` INT(11)                                                                                     NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type`      ENUM ('message', 'announcement') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'message',
  `channel`   ENUM ('general', 'private')                                              NOT NULL DEFAULT 'general',
  `posted`    DATETIME                                                                                    NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `posted` (`posted`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `channel` (`channel`),
  KEY `recipient` (`recipient`)
)
  ENGINE = MyISAM
  DEFAULT CHARSET = `utf8`
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 2;
```

Comment: Show your schema for the table.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Sorry, added the schema. Just didn't think it would help that much.

Comment: A simple `ORDER BY posted` with a LIMIT of 20 will do

Comment: Just makes it easier to write an example.answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Wouldn't that just show the last 20 items in the last hour? Heh, I'll try.

Comment: Sent in the last hour: `SELECT * FROM chat WHERE posted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`

Comment: *"Get records from last hour **or** last 20 items"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're right, bad wording on the subject. Read the description :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
(
    select * from chat
    where timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), interval 1 hour)
)
union
(   
    select * from chat order by posted desc limit 20
)
order by posted
```

Explanation:

- It selects all messages from the last hour.
- It also selects the last 20 messages, as a separate query (20 records is fast)
- The union merges the two results, and removes doubles in case there's overlap between the two

So, when there is no data in the past hour, you'll still get the 20 most recent posts. If there's a lot of data in the past hour, you'll get all of those.

Comment: This Is great! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `chat`
ORDER BY `posted` DESC
LIMIT 0,20;
```

It will list the last 20 rows (by date/time). Since you want older chats when there aren't enough within the last hour, you don't need to worry about the age of the chats.

The following is untested and may have a syntax error, so you may have to play with it a bit.

```
SELECT *
FROM `chat`
WHERE DATE_ADD(a.`posted` interval 1 hour) <= NOW()
UNION
(
    SELECT *
    FROM `chat`
    WHERE a.posted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour)
    AND (SELECT count(*) FROM `chat` WHERE a.posted <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour)) < 20
    ORDER BY `posted` DESC
    LIMIT 0,20)
ORDER BY `posted` DESC
```

It should only add the posts older than the last hour when there are less than 20 posts in the last hour.

Comment: Wouldn't that show only the last 20 messages? What if there was 100 messages sent in the last hour? I would like to show all 100 messages.

Comment: Yes that would show only the last 20. I could re-write to show all within the last hour, plus the last 20 over an hour, and you could ignore them in the code that call the query when you have enough in the last hour.

Comment: Just a tip: don't do `DATE_ADD(a.posted interval 1 hour) <= NOW()`. Instead, do `a.posted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour)`. It'll yield the same results, but it runs much faster. Your version needs to add one hour for every row in the table, which means that no index will be used either. That's going to be a lot slower. On large tables it'll be a world of difference.